# Changes not saving in django admin changelist view

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a manytomany relationship with another. I followed the example at https://gist.github.com/jdklub/9261959 to make the manytomany field editable from the changelist view. However, when I make changes only the changes to the manytomany field are actually being saved.

**admin.py**

```
class HostChangeList(ChangeList):
    def __init__(self, request, model, list_display, list_display_links,
        list_filter, date_hierarchy, search_fields, list_select_related,
        list_per_page, list_max_show_all, list_editable, model_admin):

    super(HostChangeList, self).__init__(request, model, list_display, list_display_links,
        list_filter, date_hierarchy, search_fields, list_select_related,
        list_per_page, list_max_show_all, list_editable, model_admin)

    self.list_display = ('action_checkbox', 'name', 'ip', 'fagroup', 'description', 'customer_facing', 'monitored', 'puppet', 'sso')
    self.list_editable = ['fagroup', 'description', 'customer_facing', 'monitored', 'puppet', 'sso']
    self.list_display_links = ['name']

class HostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fagroup = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=FAgroup.objects.all(),widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'size': '10'}),required=False)
    description = forms.CharField(required=False)
    customer_facing = forms.NullBooleanField()
    monitored = forms.NullBooleanField()
    puppet = forms.NullBooleanField()
    sso = forms.NullBooleanField()

class HostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return HostChangeList

    def get_changelist_form(self, request, **kwargs):
        return HostForm
```

**models.py**

```
class Host(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(default='0.0.0.0')
    fagroup = models.ManyToManyField(FAgroup)
    description = models.TextField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    customer_facing = models.NullBooleanField(default=False, null=False)
    monitored = models.NullBooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    puppet = models.NullBooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    sso = models.NullBooleanField(default=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def display_fagroups(self):
        return ', '.join([ group.name for group in self.fagroup.all() ])

class FAgroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I've even tried removing all references to the manytomany field from the ModelForm and ChangeList, but none of the fields save. It doesn't give any errors and does give the message that the records were saved, but none of the changes persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the proper way to fix this issue or not, but I was able to get it to save by overriding the built in save function for the HostAdmin class. Hopefully this is helpful to someone else looking at a similar issue.

```
class HostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name', 'ip', 'fagroup__name')
    list_filter = ('fagroup', 'customer_facing', 'monitored', 'puppet', 'sso')
    actions_on_bottom = True

    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return HostChangeList

    def get_changelist_form(self, request, **kwargs):
        return HostForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

        if form.cleaned_data['fagroup'] != obj.fagroup:
            obj.fagroup = form.cleaned_data['fagroup']
        if form.cleaned_data['description'] != obj.description:
            obj.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
        if form.cleaned_data['customer_facing'] != obj.customer_facing:
            obj.customer_facing = form.cleaned_data['customer_facing']
        if form.cleaned_data['monitored'] != obj.monitored:
            obj.monitored = form.cleaned_data['monitored']
        if form.cleaned_data['puppet'] != obj.puppet:
            obj.puppet = form.cleaned_data['puppet']
        if form.cleaned_data['sso'] != obj.sso:
            obj.sso = form.cleaned_data['sso']

        obj.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped! But you don't have to call `obj.save()` at the end, just call super.

Comment: Also, you can do it like this
`for key in form.changed_data:
    if (key not in ['fagroup']):
        setattr(obj, key, form.cleaned_data[key])
`